# How can I keep pgfplots bar chart from autoskipping unused axis labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, ticks

I'm making a bar chart. This is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.7]
    \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={2, 3, 5}, 
        xtick={2, 3, 5}, 
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5}, 
        xlabel=\$]
        \addplot[ybar, fill=blue] coordinates
        {
            (2, 2)
            (3, 3)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is what is displayed: 
[image: Chart]

How can I get latex to display all 3 xticks and all 6 yticks, even if they are not used/reached by the actual content of the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgfplots` scans over the plots and checks what domain and range are really used, and adjusts them accordingly. In order to change this, you can adjust `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` (and in 3d plots `zmin` and `zmax`). In this case, you can just add `xmax=5` and `ymax=5`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={2, 3, 5}, 
        xtick={2, 3, 5}, 
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5},
        xmax=5,ymax=5, 
        xlabel=\$]
        \addplot[ybar, fill=blue] coordinates
        {
            (2, 2)
            (3, 3)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Is there a way to add some distance between the rightmost x tick and the right edge of the chart?

Comment: @alspmrg Yes, e.g. by adding the key `enlarge x limits=0.1` or just increasing `xmax`.